# Bootstrap Media Querys

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems with bootstrap.
My Problem: i have 4 cards on my webpage (`col-md-3`). 
To make the webpage responisve i added 3 media querys:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
.col-md-3{
    width: calc(50% - 10px) !Important;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
.col-md-3{
    width: calc(33.33% - 10px) !Important;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
.col-md-3{
    width: calc(25% - 10px) !Important;
}
}
```

`600px`=should show me two cards in one row
`900px`=should show me 3 cards in one row
`1200px`=should show me 4 cards in one row

Now the 900 and 1200 media querys are working. In the crome console (f12) i found out that at `992px` there is a media query from bootstrap. If i delete it also the `600px` media query is working perfectly. How can i delete this media query from bootstrap so it doesent show up again?

Comment: Are you aware of the different classes to can give your element? They created different ones just for the purpose of not having to edit your css. col-sm-* for small devices, col-md-* for medium, col-lg-* for large.

Comment: You can name a new class differently with the bootsrap classes and set its media queries and leave the bootstrap properties behind.

Comment: Are you included your css after bootstrap files?

Comment: @Ivan yes i have included my css after the bootstrap files

Comment: well i could solve the Problem... with float:left; :)